# Functional, Declarative, and Imperative Programming

Tags: terminology, paradigms

What do the terms functional, declarative, and imperative programming mean?

Comment: There are some great answers here. One interesting thing not fully elucidated is that *declarative* and *imperative* are complementary and symbiotic, more than just different styles or *what* vs. *how*.

Comment: @Kit Imo, some of the answers on this page are conflating the terms. DP == referential transparency (RT). DP & IP are opposites, thus afaics not complements of a whole, i.e. an entire program can be written in either style. The call to a function can be either DP (RT) or IP, its implementation could be either or a mix. They are not symbiotic in the sense that a call to an IP function in an otherwise DP function can make the DP function's call IP. They are symbiotic in the sense that real world (e.g. functional reactive) programs can employ a mix, e.g. IP top level calls into DP functions.

Comment: ahould be added to the wiki or a link on something similar to the wiki etc. here is a great link in wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_paradigms

Comment: Upvote for jQuery http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492

Comment: This question is being discussed at Meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342784/2751851

Answer (score 274):

At the time of writing this, the top voted answers on this page are imprecise and muddled on the declarative vs. imperative definition, including the answer that quotes Wikipedia. Some answers are conflating the terms in different ways.

Refer also to [my explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129628/what-is-declarative-programming/8365840#8365840) of why spreadsheet programming is declarative, regardless that the formulas mutate the cells.

Also, several answers claim that functional programming must be a subset of declarative. On that point it depends if we differentiate "function" from "procedure". Lets handle imperative vs. declarative first.

**Definition of *declarative expression***

The **only** attribute that can possibly differentiate a *declarative* expression from an *imperative* expression is the referential transparency (RT) of its sub-expressions. All other attributes are either shared between both types of expressions, or derived from the RT.

A 100% declarative language (i.e. one in which every possible expression is RT) does not (among other RT requirements) allow the mutation of stored values, e.g. HTML and most of Haskell.

**Definition of *RT expression***

RT is often referred to as having "no side-effects". The term *effects* does not have a precise definition, so some people don't agree that "no side-effects" is the same as RT. RT has a [precise definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8346779):

> An expression `e` is referentially transparent if for all programs `p` every occurrence of `e` in `p` can be replaced with the result of evaluating `e`, without affecting the observable result of `p`.

Since every sub-expression is conceptually a function call, RT requires that the implementation of a function (i.e. the expression(s) inside the called function) may not access the mutable state that is *external* to the function (accessing the [mutable *local* state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8346779) is allowed). Put simply, the function (implementation) should be *pure*.

**Definition of *pure function***

A pure function is often said to have "no side-effects". The term *effects* does not have a precise definition, so some people don't agree.

Pure functions have the following attributes.

- the only observable output is the return value.
- the only output dependency is the arguments.
- arguments are fully determined before any output is generated.

Remember that RT applies to expressions (which includes function calls) and purity applies to  (implementations of) functions.

An obscure example of impure functions that make RT expressions is concurrency, but this is because the purity is broken at the interrupt abstraction layer. You don't really need to know this. To make RT expressions, you call pure functions.

**Derivative attributes of RT**

Any other attribute cited for declarative programming, e.g. the [citation from 1999](http://www.csc.liv.ac.uk/%7Efrans/OldLectures/2CS24/declarative.html#detail) used by Wikipedia, either derives from RT, or is shared with imperative programming. Thus proving that my precise definition is correct.

Note, immutability of [external values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8346779) is a subset of the requirements for RT.

- Declarative languages don't have looping control structures, e.g. `for` and `while`, because **due to immutability**, the loop condition would never change.
- Declarative languages don't express control-flow other than nested function order (a.k.a logical dependencies), because  **due to immutability**, other choices of evaluation order do not change the result (see below).
- Declarative languages express logical "steps" (i.e. the nested RT function call order), but whether each function call is a higher level semantic (i.e. "what to do") is not a requirement of declarative programming. The distinction from imperative is that **due to immutability** (i.e. more generally RT), these "steps" cannot depend on mutable state, rather only the relational order of the expressed logic (i.e. the order of nesting of the function calls, a.k.a. sub-expressions).

For example, the HTML paragraph `<p>` cannot be displayed until the sub-expressions (i.e. tags) in the paragraph have been evaluated. There is no mutable state, only an order dependency due to the logical relationship of tag hierarchy (nesting of sub-expressions, which are [analogously nested function calls](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/Kotlin/Type-safe+Groovy-style+builders?focusedCommentId=41488185#comment-41488185)).

- Thus there is the derivative attribute of immutability (more generally RT), that declarative expressions, express *only* the *logical* relationships of the constituent parts (i.e. of the sub-expression function arguments) and not *mutable state* relationships.

**Evaluation order**

The choice of evaluation order of sub-expressions can only give a varying result when any of the function calls are not RT (i.e. the function is not pure), e.g. some mutable state external to a function is accessed within the function.

For example, given some nested expressions, e.g. `f( g(a, b), h(c, d) )`, eager and lazy evaluation of the function arguments will give the same results if the functions `f`, `g`, and `h` are pure.

Whereas, if the functions `f`, `g`, and `h` are not pure, then the choice of evaluation order can give a different result.

Note, nested expressions are conceptually nested functions, since expression operators are just function calls masquerading as unary prefix, unary postfix, or binary infix notation.

Tangentially, if all identifiers, e.g. `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, are *immutable* everywhere, state external to the program cannot be accessed (i.e. I/O), and there is no abstraction layer breakage, then functions are always pure.

By the way, Haskell has a different syntax, `f (g a b) (h c d)`.

**Evaluation order details**

A function is a state transition (not a mutable stored value) from the input to the output. For RT compositions of calls to *pure* functions, the order-of-execution of these state transitions is independent. The state transition of each function call is independent of the others, due to lack of side-effects and the principle that an [RT function may be replaced by its cached value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8346779). To [correct a popular misconception](http://goldwetrust.up-with.com/t112p180-computers#4434), pure monadic composition is **[always declarative and RT](http://candleapp.blogspot.com/2011/12/2-misconcepts-about-functional.html?showComment=1323267588192#c5825897491390894567)**, in spite of the fact that Haskell's `IO` monad is [arguably impure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4392603/615784) and thus imperative w.r.t. the `World` state external to the program (but in the sense of the caveat below, the side-effects are isolated).

Eager evaluation means the functions arguments are evaluated before the function is called, and lazy evaluation means the [arguments are not evaluated](http://augustss.blogspot.com/2011/04/ugly-memoization-heres-problem-that-i.html#c7176854531514039037) until (and if) they are accessed within the function.

**Definition**: function *parameters* are declared at the function *definition* site, and function *arguments* are supplied at the function *call* site. Know the difference between *parameter* and *argument*.

Conceptually, all expressions are (a composition of) function calls, e.g. constants are functions without inputs, unary operators are functions with one input, binary infix operators are functions with two inputs, constructors are functions, and even control statements (e.g. `if`, `for`, `while`) can be modeled with functions. The [order that these](http://augustss.blogspot.com/2011/04/ugly-memoization-heres-problem-that-i.html#c7176854531514039037) *argument* functions (do not confuse with nested function call order) are evaluated is not declared by the syntax, e.g. `f( g() )` could eagerly evaluate `g` then `f` on `g`'s result or it could evaluate `f` and only lazily evaluate `g` when its result is needed within `f`.

Caveat, no [Turing complete](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8283566) language (i.e. that allows unbounded recursion) is perfectly declarative, e.g. lazy evaluation introduces memory and time indeterminism. But these side-effects due to the choice of evaluation order are limited to memory consumption, execution time, latency, non-termination, and [external hysteresis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357918/what-does-hysteresis-mean-and-how-does-it-apply-to-computer-science-or-programmi) thus external synchronization.

**Functional programming**

Because declarative programming cannot have loops, then the only way to iterate is functional recursion. It is in this sense that functional programming is related to declarative programming.

But **functional programming is not limited to declarative programming**. Functional composition can be [contrasted with subtyping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8352969), especially with respect to the [Expression Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596366/what-is-the-expression-problem), where extension can be achieved by [either adding subtypes or functional decomposition](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/IC_TECH_REPORT_200433.pdf#). [Extension can be a mix](http://beust.com/weblog2/archives/000490.html) of both methodologies.

Functional programming usually makes the function a first-class object, meaning the function type can appear in the grammar anywhere any other type may. The upshot is that functions can input and operate on functions, thus providing for separation-of-concerns by emphasizing function composition, i.e. separating the dependencies among the subcomputations of a deterministic computation.

For example, [instead of writing a separate function](http://www.unsafeperformio.com/papers/thesis.pdf#page=18) (and employing recursion instead of loops if the function must also be declarative) for each of an infinite number of possible specialized actions that could be applied to each element of a collection, functional programming employs reusable iteration functions, e.g. `map`, `fold`, `filter`. These iteration functions input a first-class specialized action function. These iteration functions iterate the collection and call the input specialized action function for each element. These action functions are more concise because they no longer need to contain the looping statements to iterate the collection.

However, note that if a function is not pure, then it is really a procedure. We can perhaps argue that functional programming that uses impure functions, is really procedural programming. Thus if we agree that declarative expressions are RT, then we can say that procedural programming is not declarative programming, and thus we might argue that functional programming is always RT and must be a subset of declarative programming.

**Parallelism**

This functional composition with first-class functions can express the [depth in the parallelism](http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/parallelism-is-not-concurrency/) by separating out the independent function.

> Brent’s Principle: computation with work w and depth d can be
> implemented in a p-processor PRAM in time O(max(w/p, d)).

Both concurrency and parallelism also [require declarative programming](http://ghcmutterings.wordpress.com/2009/10/06/parallelism-concurrency/), i.e. immutability and RT.

> So where did this dangerous assumption that Parallelism == Concurrency
> come from?  It’s a natural consequence of languages with side-effects:
> when your language has side-effects everywhere, then any time you try
> to do more than one thing at a time you essentially have
> non-determinism caused by the interleaving of the effects from each
> operation.  So in side-effecty languages, the only way to get
> parallelism is concurrency; it’s therefore not surprising that we
> often see the two conflated.

### FP evaluation order

Note the evaluation order also impacts the termination and performance side-effects of functional composition.

Eager (CBV) and lazy (CBN) are categorical duels[[10](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/andrzej/papers/DCaCD.ps.gz)], because they have reversed evaluation order, i.e. whether the outer or inner functions respectively are evaluated first. Imagine an upside-down tree, then eager evaluates from function tree branch tips up the branch hierarchy to the top-level function trunk; whereas, lazy evaluates from the trunk down to the branch tips. Eager doesn't have conjunctive products ("and", a/k/a categorical "products") and lazy doesn't have disjunctive coproducts ("or", a/k/a categorical "sums")[[11](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/andrzej/papers/DCaCD.ps.gz)].

**Performance**

- Eager

As with non-termination, eager is too eager with conjunctive functional composition, i.e. compositional control structure does unnecessary work that isn't done with lazy. For [example](http://augustss.blogspot.com/2011/05/more-points-for-lazy-evaluation-in.html), eager eagerly and unnecessarily maps the entire list to booleans, when it is composed with a fold that terminates on the first true element.

This unnecessary work is the cause of the claimed "up to" an extra [log n factor](http://goldwetrust.up-with.com/t112p180-computers#4437) in the sequential time complexity of eager versus lazy, both with pure functions. A solution is to use functors (e.g. lists) with lazy constructors (i.e. eager with optional lazy products), because with eager the eagerness incorrectness originates from the inner function. This is because products are constructive types, i.e. inductive types with an initial algebra on an initial fixpoint[[11](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/andrzej/papers/DCaCD.ps.gz)]

- Lazy

As with non-termination, lazy is too lazy with disjunctive functional composition, i.e. coinductive finality can occur later than necessary, resulting in both unnecessary work and non-determinism of the lateness that isn't the case with eager[[10](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/andrzej/papers/DCaCD.ps.gz)][[11](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/andrzej/papers/DCaCD.ps.gz)]. Examples of finality are state, timing, non-termination, and runtime exceptions. These are imperative side-effects, but even in a pure declarative language (e.g. Haskell), there is state in the imperative IO monad (note: not all monads are imperative!) implicit in space allocation, and timing is state relative to the imperative real world. Using lazy even with optional eager coproducts leaks "laziness" into inner coproducts, because with lazy the laziness incorrectness [originates from the outer function](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2273#comment-40174) (see the example in the Non-termination section, where == is an outer binary operator function). This is because coproducts are bounded by finality, i.e. coinductive types with a final algebra on an final object[[11](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/andrzej/papers/DCaCD.ps.gz)].

Lazy causes indeterminism in the design and debugging of functions for latency and space, the debugging of which is probably beyond the capabilities of the majority of programmers, because of the [dissonance between](http://goldwetrust.up-with.com/t112p195-computers#4487) the declared function hierarchy and the runtime order-of-evaluation. Lazy pure functions evaluated with eager, could potentially introduce previously unseen non-termination at runtime. Conversely, eager pure functions evaluated with lazy, could potentially introduce previously unseen space and latency indeterminism at runtime.

**Non-termination**

At compile-time, due to the Halting problem and mutual recursion in a Turing complete language, functions can't generally be guaranteed to terminate.

- Eager

With eager but not lazy, for the conjunction of `Head` "and" `Tail`, if either `Head` or `Tail` doesn't terminate, then respectively either `List( Head(), Tail() ).tail == Tail()` or `List( Head(), Tail() ).head == Head()` is not true because the left-side doesn't, and right-side does, terminate.

Whereas, with lazy both sides terminate. Thus eager is too eager with conjunctive products, and non-terminates (including runtime exceptions) in those cases where it isn't necessary.

- Lazy

With lazy but not eager, for the disjunction of `1` "or" `2`, if `f` doesn't terminate, then `List( f ? 1 : 2, 3 ).tail == (f ? List( 1, 3 ) : List( 2, 3 )).tail` is not true because the left-side terminates, and right-side doesn't.

Whereas, with eager neither side terminates so the equality test is never reached. Thus lazy is too lazy with disjunctive coproducts, and in those cases fails to terminate (including runtime exceptions) after doing more work than eager would have.

[[10](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/andrzej/papers/DCaCD.ps.gz)] Declarative Continuations and Categorical Duality, Filinski, sections 2.5.4 A comparison of CBV and CBN, and 3.6.1 CBV and CBN in the SCL.

[[11](http://www.diku.dk/hjemmesider/ansatte/andrzej/papers/DCaCD.ps.gz)] Declarative Continuations and Categorical Duality, Filinski, sections 2.2.1 Products and coproducts, 2.2.2 Terminal and initial objects, 2.5.2 CBV with lazy products, and 2.5.3 CBN with eager coproducts.

Comment: Even with declarative constraint programming, the constraints don't mutate while the solver is finding the solution. This is obvious because there is no way to specify a time for them to change. Even constraints specified w.r.t. other constraints all are stated before the solver is run to find the solution. This is analogous to the declarative [formulas in the spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129628/what-is-declarative-programming/8365840#8365840).

Comment: Abbreviation does not mean provide a definition. Where I wrote "RT is often abbreviated 'no side-effects'", that doesn't mean the definition of RT is "no side-effects", because people may have varying definitions for 'effects'. If I instead said "RT is often abbreviated 'xyz'", a meaningless symbol doesn't give any definition to RT. [RT has a _precise_ definition](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8346779) that never changes, no matter what symbol one uses to refer to it.

Comment: I am unable to find a counter-example to my claim that every kind of DP is RT. For example, the meaning (i.e. value) of the terms of a context-sensitive grammar don't mutate at a different time or position within the grammar. See my constraint programming comment above.

Comment: Equating [C in ESP style](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4327#comment-66506) with RT in State monad, is [invalid](http://candleapp.blogspot.com/2011/12/2-misconcepts-about-functional.html?showComment=1323267987588#c6746182628699496455), because each C statement may mutate global state, whereas "inside" the state monad each corresponding statement generates a **COPY** of the state (so modified). The latter is RT-- former is not. Monadic composition is _always_ RT. DP == RT is the only meaning for DP that is a disjoint set of attributes (the math proof I'm correct, else DP is meaningless).

Comment: When mentioning checking for termination, it is worth mentioning that not all languages are turing complete and in those you can in fact ensure that functions are total, eg. Applicative Common Lisp 2.

Comment: Some people have stated that SQL is a declarative language. If that is the case, doesn't SQL not have RT, since it can modify state (tables in a database)? Calling the same SQL query at the beginning and end of a program will produce different results.

Comment: You say declarative programming can not have loops. But I can imagine a pure function which does contain loops, i.e. it loops through a local collection, or a collection passed into the function as an argument. Is it not more accurate to say that a declarative language has no need for loops?

Comment: In a true Declarative language, wouldn't you not implement Functions, but simply choose which function to use, in what order, and with what values? By that I mean, even in a Pure Functional language, isn't the implementation of a function imperative?

Comment: I wish I could understand this past the first sentence. I was reading the manual for DAX which indicated it was a 'functional language'. What does this mean? I don't know go ask your pop.

Comment: The definition of *referential transparency* that you quoted is not sourced and does not match the definition in the literature; see [Uday Reddy’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9859966/2326961) for the correct definition.

Comment: Quite some effort — yet more the opinion or view of one person. this explanation ie contradicts the Wikipedia article that lists FP as sub paradigm of Declarative Programming. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming#Functional_programming

Comment: also: @ShelbyMooreIII does not distinguish between "Declarative Programming" and "Declarative Languages" . also his definition comes form a student assay for 1999 which looks into languages, not coding styles.

Comment: "the only output dependency is the arguments." This part of the definition of pure functions imply that closures are not allowed...?

Answer (score 106):

There's not really any non-ambiguous, objective definition for these.  Here is how *I* would define them:

**Imperative** - The focus is on what steps the computer should take rather than what the computer will *do* (ex. C, C++, Java).

**Declarative** - The focus is on what the computer should do rather than how it should do it (ex. SQL).

**Functional** - a subset of declarative languages that has heavy focus on recursion

Comment: Recursion isn't the only feature of functional languages.  They also have ways of dealing with functions other than just compilation, perhaps for example allowing runtime combination of functions to get a new function.

Comment: Keep a couple of things in mind:  1) the explanation is intended to be simple rather than all-inclusive 2) like I said, there are multiple ways to define these languages.  Thus, the answer could very well be wrong to you and right to someone else.

Comment: Functional programming is **not** "a subset of declarative languages". Declarative programming requires the immutability of stored values, functional programming does not, if it is not _pure_ FP. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8357604). See also the [explanation for spreadsheet cells](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8365840). The correct _objective_ definitions are not "ambiguous". Imperative programming is also focused "on what the computer should do". The **only** distinction is imperative programming has to deal with mutable stored values.

Comment: @ShelbyMooreIII - I tend to agree with Eric Meijer on this one.  There's not really such thing as a "non-pure functional language".  As far as I'm concerned, Ocaml, F#, and the like are imperative languages with functional data structures.  But as I said in my answer, I don't believe there's any objective, non-ambiguous answer to this question.  There are multiple ways of defining things.

Comment: One can mathematically prove that he is conflating terms, when none of definitions are unambiguous, because the chosen attributes aren't a disjoint set. If you define FP as _only pure_ FP (i.e. RT), then it is not distinct from DP, cf. [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8357604). The disjoint attributes of FP includes the first-class function type, which can be an imperative function. I found more fundamental terms ambiguity [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19132/615784) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8450076/615784). Preferring _pure_ FP is orthogonal to the definition of just FP.

Comment: Someone else [explains my point](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4382400/615784).

Comment: @ShelbyMooreIII - I was making the assumption that the OP wanted his answer in English, not Math Nerd-ese.  If that was an invalid assumption, then my apologies.

Comment: @JasonBaker I am trying to be friendly while helping people understand the difference between things. Sometimes that may come across as snobbish, nerdy, or pedantic. Apologies also. I am confident I will learn from you too. Programming is very related to the logic of sets. This is basically what typing is. This will become a much more important skill with the rise of Scala and the ilk.

Comment: @JasonBaker I edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8357604/615784), and under the "Functional programming" section, I added a scenario where we could argue that FP is always pure, and impure FP is really "procedural programming". Apologies for not including that interpretation earlier.

Comment: LINQ feature in C# language is functional by nature when the language itself is imperative. C# also has attributes e.g. `[Serializable]` with the help of which you can decorate your classes and methods. Those attributes are also functional in nature.

Comment: FP is a subset of imperative programming. There are only 2 classes: imperative and declarative.

Comment: best explanation of all time.

Answer (score 62):

**imperative** and **declarative** describe two opposing styles of programming.  imperative is the traditional "step by step recipe" approach while declarative is more "this is what i want, now you work out how to do it".

these two approaches occur throughout programming - even with the same language and the same program.  generally the declarative approach is considered preferable, because it frees the programmer from having to specify so many details, while also having less chance for bugs (if you describe the result you want, and some well-tested automatic process can work backwards from that to define the steps then you might hope that things are more reliable than having to specify each step by hand).

on the other hand, an imperative approach gives you more low level control - it's the "micromanager approach" to programming.  and that can allow the programmer to exploit knowledge about the problem to give a more efficient answer.  so it's not unusual for some parts of a program to be written in a more declarative style, but for the speed-critical parts to be more imperative.

as you might imagine, the language you use to write a program affects how declarative you can be - a language that has built-in "smarts" for working out what to do given a description of the result is going to allow a much more declarative approach than one where the programmer needs to first add that kind of intelligence with imperative code before being able to build a more declarative layer on top.  so, for example, a language like prolog is considered very declarative because it has, built-in, a process that searches for answers.

so far, you'll notice that i haven't mentioned **functional** programming.  that's because it's a term whose meaning isn't immediately related to the other two.  at its most simple, functional programming means that you use functions.  in particular, that you use a language that supports functions as "first class values" - that means that not only can you write functions, but you can write functions that write functions (that write functions that...), and pass functions to functions.  in short - that functions are as flexible and common as things like strings and numbers.

it might seem odd, then, that functional, imperative and declarative are often mentioned together.  the reason for this is a consequence of taking the idea of functional programming "to the extreme".  a function, in it's purest sense, is something from maths - a kind of "black box" that takes some input and always gives the same output.  and that kind of behaviour doesn't require storing changing variables.  so if you design a programming language whose aim is to implement a very pure, mathematically influenced idea of functional programming, you end up rejecting, largely, the idea of values that can change (in a certain, limited, technical sense).

and if you do that - if you limit how variables can change - then almost by accident you end up forcing the programmer to write programs that are more declarative, because a large part of imperative programming is describing how variables change, and you can no longer do that!  so it turns out that functional programming - particularly, programming in a functional language - tends to give more declarative code.

to summarise, then:

- imperative and declarative are two opposing styles of programming (the same names are used for programming languages that encourage those styles)
- functional programming is a style of programming where functions become very important and, as a consequence, changing values become less important.  the limited ability to specify changes in values forces a more declarative style.

so "functional programming" is often described as "declarative".

Comment: Best explanation so far. It seems Functional and OOP are orthogonal to Imperative and Declarative.

Comment: Would you say Logic Programming is Declarative? Or is it itself orthogonal?

Answer (score 51):

In a nutshell:

An **imperative language** specfies a series of instructions that the computer executes in sequence (do this, then do that).

A **declarative language** declares a set of rules about what outputs should result from which inputs (eg. if you have A, then the result is B).  An engine will apply these rules to inputs, and give an output.

A **functional language** declares a set of mathematical/logical functions which define how input is translated to output.  eg. f(y) = y * y.  it is a type of declarative language.

Comment: Functional programming is **not** "a type of declarative language". Declarative programming requires the immutability of stored values, _impure_ functional programming does not. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8357604). See also the [explanation for spreadsheet cells](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8365840). The **only** reason imperative logic (a.k.a instructions) execute in sequence is that due to the presence of mutable stored values, the result is dependent on the evaluation order. Using your vocabulary, an "instruction" can (and a "rule" cannot) operate on mutable values.

Answer (score 25):

Imperative: ***how*** to achieve our goal

```
   Take the next customer from a list.
   If the customer lives in Spain, show their details.
   If there are more customers in the list, go to the beginning
```

Declarative: ***what*** we want to achieve

```
   Show customer details of every customer living in Spain
```

Comment: You are describing functional programming vs. non-FP, not declarative vs. imperative programming. Functional programming is orthogonal to the polarity between imperative and declarative programming. Declarative programming requires the immutability of stored values, _impure_ functional programming does not. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8357604).

Answer (score 23):

**Imperative Programming** means any style of programming where your program is structured out of instructions **describing how the operations performed by a computer will happen**.

**Declarative Programming** means any style of programming where your program is a description either of the problem or the solution - but **doesn't explicitly state how the work will be done**.

**Functional Programming** is programming by evaluating functions and functions of functions... As (strictly defined) functional programming means programming by defining side-effect free mathematical functions so it **is a form of declarative programming but it isn't the only kind of declarative programming**.

**Logic Programming** (for example in Prolog) is another form of declarative programming. It involves computing by deciding whether a logical statement is true (or whether it can be satisfied). The program is typically a series of facts and rules - i.e. a description rather than a series of instructions.

**Term Rewriting** (for example CASL) is another form of declarative programming. It involves symbolic transformation of algebraic terms. It's completely distinct from logic programming and functional programming.

Comment: Functional programming is **not** "a form of declarative programming". Declarative programming requires the immutability of stored values, _impure_ functional programming does not. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8357604). See also the [explanation for spreadsheet cells](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8365840). The term "work" in "describe how to do the work" is not defined. The **only** reason imperative logic (a.k.a "instructions") execute in sequence is that due to the presence of mutable stored values, the result is dependent on the evaluation order.

Comment: *Please take it as read that I was talking about pure functional programming*. These paradigms can cross over and I don't want to get bogged down comparing hybrid languages. In theory at least functional programming is about functions rather than describing how a computer will perform each computation - so I maintain it is declarative.

Comment: I edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8357604/615784), and under the "Functional programming" section, I added a scenario where we could argue that FP is always pure, and impure FP is really "procedural programming". Apologies for not including that interpretation earlier.

Answer (score 16):

**imperative** - expressions describe sequence of actions to perform (associative)

**declarative** - expressions are declarations that contribute to behavior of program (associative, commutative, idempotent, monotonic)

**functional** - expressions have *value* as only effect; semantics support equational reasoning

Comment: Declarative expressions contribute to the [*intended*](http://copute.com/edu/Intro%20to%20Computers.html#Declarative) behavior of the program, imperative can contribute to intended or unintended. Declarative doesn't need to be commutative and idempotent, if this is intentional semantics. I like your concise essence of functional, so I upvoted it.

Answer (score 14):

Since I wrote my prior answer, I have formulated a [new definition](https://web.archive.org/web/20140820201009/http://copute.com/edu/Intro%20to%20Computers.html) of the declarative property which is quoted below. I have also defined imperative programming as the dual property.

This definition is superior to the one I provided in my prior answer, because it is succinct and it is more general. But it may be more difficult to grok, because the implication of the incompleteness theorems applicable to programming and life in general are difficult for humans to wrap their mind around.

The quoted explanation of the definition discusses the role *pure* functional programming plays in declarative programming.

All exotic types of programming fit into the following taxonomy of declarative versus imperative, since the following definition claims they are duals.

> **Declarative vs. Imperative**
>
> The declarative property is weird, obtuse, and difficult to capture in a technically precise definition that remains general and not ambiguous, because it is a naive notion that we can declare the meaning (a.k.a semantics) of the program without incurring unintended side effects. There is an inherent tension between expression of meaning and avoidance of unintended effects, and this tension actually derives from the [incompleteness theorems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem#Relationship_with_G.C3.B6del.27s_incompleteness_theorems) of programming and our universe.
>
> It is oversimplification, technically imprecise, and often ambiguous to define declarative as **“*what to do*”** and imperative as **“*how to do*”**. An ambiguous case is the “*what*” is the “*how*” in a program that outputs a program— a compiler.
>
> Evidently the [unbounded recursion that makes a language Turing complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284/what-is-turing-complete/8283566#8283566), is also analogously in the semantics— not only in the syntactical structure of evaluation (a.k.a. operational semantics). This is logically an example analogous to Gödel's theorem— “*any complete system of axioms is also inconsistent*”. Ponder the contradictory weirdness of that quote! It is also an example that demonstrates how the expression of semantics does not have a provable bound, thus we can't prove[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem#Relationship_with_G.C3.B6del.27s_incompleteness_theorems) that a program (and analogously its semantics) halt a.k.a. the Halting theorem.
>
> The incompleteness theorems derive from the fundamental nature of our universe, which as stated in the Second Law of Thermodynamics is “*the entropy* (a.k.a. the # of independent possibilities) *is trending to maximum forever*”. The coding and design of a program is never finished— it's alive!— because it attempts to address a real world need, and the semantics of the real world are always changing and trending to more possibilities. Humans never stop discovering new things (including errors in programs ;-).
>
> To precisely and technically capture this aforementioned desired notion within this weird universe that has no edge (ponder that! there is no “outside” of our universe), requires a terse but deceptively-not-simple definition which will sound incorrect until it is explained deeply.
>
> Definition:
>
> > ---
> >
> > The declarative property is where there can exist only one possible set of statements that can express each specific modular semantic.
> >
> > The imperative property[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284/what-is-turing-complete/8283566#8283566) is the dual, where semantics are inconsistent under composition and/or can be expressed with variations of sets of statements.
> >
> > ---
>
> This definition of declarative is distinctively *local* in semantic scope, meaning that it requires that a modular semantic maintain its consistent meaning regardless where and how it's instantiated and employed in *global* scope. Thus each declarative modular semantic should be intrinsically orthogonal to all possible others— and not an impossible (due to incompleteness theorems) *global* algorithm or model for witnessing consistency, which is also the point of “[*More Is Not Always Better*](http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2013/01/28/more-is-not-always-better/)” by Robert Harper, Professor of Computer Science at Carnegie Mellon University, one of the designers of Standard ML.
>
> Examples of these modular declarative semantics include category theory functors e.g. [the `Applicative`](http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=4824&cpage=1#comment-396497), nominal typing, namespaces, named fields, and w.r.t. to operational level of semantics then pure functional programming.
>
> Thus well designed declarative languages can [more clearly express meaning](http://esr.ibiblio.org/?p=4824&cpage=1#comment-396175), albeit with some loss of generality in what can be expressed, yet a gain in what can be expressed with intrinsic consistency.
>
> An example of the aforementioned definition is the set of formulas in the cells of a spreadsheet program— which are not expected to give the same meaning when moved to different column and row cells, i.e. cell identifiers changed. The cell identifiers are part of and not superfluous to the intended meaning. So each spreadsheet result is unique w.r.t. to the cell identifiers in a set of formulas. The consistent modular semantic in this case is use of cell identifiers as the input and output of *pure* functions for cells formulas (see below).
>
> Hyper Text Markup Language a.k.a. HTML— the language for static web pages— is an example of a highly (but not perfectly[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284/what-is-turing-complete/8283566#8283566)) declarative language that (at least before HTML 5) had no capability to express dynamic behavior. HTML is perhaps the easiest language to learn. For dynamic behavior, an imperative scripting language such as JavaScript was usually combined with HTML. HTML without JavaScript fits the declarative definition because each nominal type (i.e. the tags) maintains its consistent meaning under composition within the rules of the syntax.
>
> A competing definition for declarative is the [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) and [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) properties of the semantic statements, i.e. that statements can be reordered and duplicated without changing the meaning. For example, statements assigning values to named fields can be reordered and duplicated without changed the meaning of the program, if those names are modular w.r.t. to any implied order. Names sometimes imply an order, e.g. cell identifiers include their column and row position— moving a total on spreadsheet changes its meaning. Otherwise, these properties implicitly require *global* consistency of semantics. It is generally impossible to design the semantics of statements so they remain consistent if randomly ordered or duplicated, because order and duplication are intrinsic to semantics. For example, the statements “Foo exists” (or construction) and “Foo does not exist” (and destruction). If one considers random inconsistency endemical of the intended semantics, then one accepts this definition as general enough for the declarative property. In essence this definition is vacuous as a generalized definition because it attempts to make consistency orthogonal to semantics, i.e. to defy the fact that the universe of semantics is dynamically unbounded and can't be captured in a *global* coherence paradigm.
>
> Requiring the commutative and idempotent properties for the (structural evaluation order of the) lower-level operational semantics converts operational semantics to a declarative *localized* modular semantic, e.g. **pure** functional programming (including recursion instead of imperative loops). Then the operational order of the implementation details do not impact (i.e. spread *globally* into) the consistency of the higher-level semantics. For example, the order of evaluation of (and theoretically also the duplication of) the spreadsheet formulas doesn't matter because the outputs are not copied to the inputs until after all outputs have been computed, i.e. analogous to pure functions.
>
> C, Java, C++, C#, PHP, and JavaScript aren't particularly declarative.
>   Copute's syntax and Python's syntax are more declaratively [coupled to
>   intended results](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3882), i.e. consistent syntactical semantics that eliminate the extraneous so one can readily
>   comprehend code after they've forgotten it. Copute and Haskell enforce
>   determinism of the operational semantics and encourage “[don't repeat
>   yourself](http://pages.citebite.com/d1i2g0d2b4chn)” (DRY), because they only allow the pure functional paradigm.
>
> ---
>
> [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem#Relationship_with_G.C3.B6del.27s_incompleteness_theorems) Even where we can prove the semantics of a program, e.g. with the language Coq, this is limited to the semantics that are expressed in [the typing](http://copute.com/edu/Intro%20to%20Computers.html#Typed), and typing can never capture all of the semantics of a program— not even for languages that are not Turing complete, e.g. with HTML+CSS it is possible to express inconsistent combinations which thus have undefined semantics.
>
> [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284/what-is-turing-complete/8283566#8283566) Many explanations incorrectly claim that only imperative programming has syntactically ordered statements. I clarified this [confusion between imperative and functional programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925689/functional-programming-vs-declarative-programming-vs-imperative-programming/15357346#15357346). For example, the order of HTML statements does not reduce the consistency of their meaning.

---

Edit: I posted the [following comment](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2013/07/22/there-is-such-a-thing-as-a-declarative-language/#comment-3138) to Robert Harper's blog:

> > in functional programming ... the range of variation of a variable is a type
>
> Depending on how one distinguishes functional from imperative
>   programming, your ‘assignable’ in an imperative program also may have
>   a type placing a bound on its variability.
>
> The only non-muddled definition I currently appreciate for functional
>   programming is a) functions as first-class objects and types, b)
>   preference for recursion over loops, and/or c) pure functions— i.e.
>   those functions which do not impact the desired semantics of the
>   program when memoized (<sub><sup>thus perfectly pure functional
>   programming doesn't exist in a general purpose denotational semantics
>   due to impacts of operational semantics, e.g. memory
>   allocation</sup></sub>).
>
> The idempotent property of a pure function means the function call on
>   its variables can be substituted by its value, which is not generally
>   the case for the arguments of an imperative procedure. Pure functions
>   seem to be declarative w.r.t. to the uncomposed state transitions
>   between the input and result types.
>
> But the composition of pure functions does not maintain any such
>   consistency, because it is possible to model a side-effect (global
>   state) imperative process in a pure functional programming language,
>   e.g. Haskell's IOMonad and moreover it is entirely impossible to
>   prevent doing such in any Turing complete pure functional programming
>   language.
>
> As I [wrote](https://awelonblue.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/defining-declarative/#comment-269) in 2012 which seems to the similar consensus of
>   comments in [your recent blog](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/what-if-anything-is-a-declarative-language/), that declarative programming is an
>   attempt to capture the notion that the intended semantics are never
>   opaque. Examples of opaque semantics are dependence on order,
>   dependence on erasure of higher-level semantics at the operational
>   semantics layer (e.g. [casts are not conversions and reified generics
>   limit higher-level semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166840/what-is-the-difference-between-casting-and-conversion/#answer-8464968)), and dependence on variable values
>   which can not be checked (proved correct) by the programming language.
>
> Thus I have concluded that only non-Turing complete languages can be
>   declarative.
>
> Thus one unambiguous and distinct attribute of a declarative language
>   could be that its output can be proven to obey some enumerable set of
>   generative rules. For example, for any specific HTML program (ignoring
>   differences in the ways interpreters diverge) that is not scripted
>   (i.e. is not Turing complete) then its output variability can be
>   enumerable. Or more succinctly an HTML program is a pure function of
>   its variability. Ditto a spreadsheet program is a pure function of its
>   input variables.
>
> So it seems to me that declarative languages are the antithesis of
>   [unbounded recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284/what-is-turing-complete/#answer-8283566), i.e. per Gödel's second incompleteness
>   theorem self-referential theorems can't be proven.
>
> Lesie Lamport [wrote](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/euclid.pdf) a fairytale about how Euclid might have
>   worked around Gödel's incompleteness theorems applied to math proofs
>   in the programming language context by to congruence between types and
>   logic (Curry-Howard correspondence, etc).

Comment: Robert Harper seems to agree with me about the [meaninglessness of most definitions of declarative](http://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/what-if-anything-is-a-declarative-language/), yet I don't think he has seen mine above. He does move close to my definition where he discusses denotational semantics, yet he doesn't get to my definition. The [model (denotational semantics) is higher-level](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-language/lChLcLES_Dk/b78ywjsHcbMJ).

Comment: How do you classify SQL?

Answer (score 9):

Imperative programming: telling the “machine” how to do something, and as a result what you want to happen will happen.

Declarative programming: telling the “machine” what you would like to happen, and letting the computer figure out how to do it.

#### Example of imperative

```
function makeWidget(options) {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.style.backgroundColor = options.bgColor;
    element.style.width = options.width;
    element.style.height = options.height;
    element.textContent = options.txt;

    return element;
}
```

#### Example of declarative

```
function makeWidget(type, txt) {
    return new Element(type, txt);
}
```

Note: The difference is not one of brevity or complexity or abstraction. As stated, the difference is *how* vs *what*.

Comment: good one but better if you provide at least one example for both !

Answer (score 4):

I think that your taxonomy is incorrect. There are two opposite types imperative and declarative. Functional is just a subtype of declarative. BTW, wikipedia states the same fact.

Comment: +1: Yep, the paradigms are apples and oranges.

Comment: FP is **not** "just a subtype of declarative". FP is orthogonal to the polarity of imperative vs. DP. DP [requires](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8357604) the immutability of stored values, _impure_ FP doesn't. Wikipedia is conflating _pure_ FP with FP, with the [absurd claim](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Functional_programming&oldid=462854133#Concepts) that the following concepts are "generally foreign to imperative programming": first-class functions, recursion, evaluation order, and static typing. Then Wikipedia admits _impure_ "Functional programming in non-functional languages".

Comment: Wikipedia is wrong on this point. Many popular functional languages allow programming in a "declarative style," if you choose, but are not declarative languages. But the same could be said of C, where you can still program in a functional style if you choose, using void*s.

Comment: Probably, I should have been more clear on this point, but from the other side, I wouldn't be going to mess topic starter with not-quite relevant (imo) details. I see that functional languages tend to be used declaratively. You can try to write declaratively and/or functionally in ASM or C or you can probably write imperative program in Lisp but I doubt that it would be very helpful or informative for the question author. So in essence I still consider my answer appropriate, even if it could be differently worded.

Answer (score 4):

### Nowadays, new focus: we need the old  classifications?

The  *Imperative/Declarative/Functional* aspects was good in the past to classify generic languages, but in nowadays all "big language" (as Java, Python, Javascript, etc.) have some option (typically [frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework)) to  express with "other focus" than its main one (usual imperative), and to express parallel processes, declarative functions, lambdas, etc.

So a good variant of this question is *"What aspect is good  to classify frameworks today?"*
... An important aspect is something that we can labeling *"programming style"*...

### Focus on the fusion of data with algorithm

A good example to explain. As you can [read about jQuery at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery),

> The set of jQuery core features — DOM element selections, traversal and manipulation —, enabled by its selector engine (...), created a new "programming style", fusing algorithms and DOM-data-structures

So jQuery is the best (popular) example of focusing on a *"new programming style"*, that is not only object orientation, is "**Fusing** [algorithms and data-structures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_%2B_Data_Structures_%3D_Programs)". jQuery is somewhat reactive as spreadsheets, but not "cell-oriented", is "*DOM-node oriented*"... Comparing the main *styles* in this context:

1. **No fusion**: in all "big languages", in any Functional/Declarative/Imperative expression, the usual is "no fusion" of data and algorithm, except by some object-orientation, that is a *fusion* in [strict algebric structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure) point of view.
2. **Some fusion**: all classic strategies of fusion, in nowadays have some framework using it as paradigm...  [dataflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_programming),   [Event-driven programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) (or old domain specific languages as [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awk) and [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT))... Like programming with modern spreadsheets, they are also examples of **[reactive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming)** style.
3. **Big fusion**: is "the jQuery style"... jQuery is a domain specific language focusing on "*fusing* algorithms and [DOM-data-structures](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html)".  
   PS: other "query languages", as XQuery,  SQL (with PL as imperative expression option) are also data-algorith-fusion examples, but they are *islands*, with no fusion with other system modules... [Spring](https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/), when using  `find()`-variants and *Specification* clauses, is another good fusion example.

Answer (score 3):

Declarative programming is programming by expressing some timeless logic between the input and the output, for instance, in pseudocode, the following example would be declarative:

```
def factorial(n):
  if n < 2:
    return 1
  else:
    return factorial(n-1)

output = factorial(argvec[0])
```

We just define a relationship called the 'factorial' here, and defined the relationship between the output and the input as the that relationship. As should be evident here, about any structured language allows declarative programming to some extend. A central idea of declarative programming is immutable data, if you assign to a variable, you only do so once, and then never again. Other, stricter definitions entail that there may be no side-effects at all, these languages are some times called 'purely declarative'.

The same result in an imperative style would be:

```
a = 1
b = argvec[0]
while(b < 2):
  a * b--

output = a
```

In this example, we expressed no timeless static logical relationship between the input and the output, we changed memory addresses manually until one of them held the desired result. It should be evident that all languages allow declarative semantics to some extend, but not all allow imperative, some 'purely' declarative languages permit side effects and mutation altogether.

Declarative languages are often said to specify 'what must be done', as opposed to 'how to do it', I think that is a misnomer, declarative programs still specify how one must get from input to output, but in another way, the relationship you specify must be *effectively computable* (important term, look it up if you don't know it). Another approach is *nondeterministic* programming, that really just specifies what conditions a result much meet, before your implementation just goes to exhaust all paths on trial and error until it succeeds.

Purely declarative languages include Haskell and Pure Prolog. A sliding scale from one and to the other would be: Pure Prolog, Haskell, OCaml, Scheme/Lisp, Python, Javascript, C--, Perl, PHP, C++, Pascall, C, Fortran, Assembly

Comment: You did not define functional programming. You incorrectly implied, "some 'purely' declarative languages", that declarative programming can be _impure_. Declarative programming requires the immutability of stored values, imperative programming does not. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8357604). Immutability is the "timeless" quality-- see that your declarative `factorial` doesn't mutate any value.

Answer (score 3):

Some good answers here regarding the noted "types".

I submit some additional, more "exotic" concepts often associated with the functional programming crowd:

- **Domain Specific Language** or **DSL** Programming: creating a new language to deal with the problem at hand.
- **Meta-Programming**: when your program writes other programs.
- **Evolutionary Programming**: where you build a system that continually improves itself or generates successively better generations of sub-programs.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, the more a programming style emphasizes What (to do) abstracting away the details of How (to do it) the more that style is considered to be declarative.  The opposite is true for imperative.  Functional programming is associated with the declarative style.

Comment: See my comments below the other answers. FP is not always declarative. What vs. how is the wrong taxonomy for IP vs. DP, as both DP and IP have logic that involve the what and how.