# Difference in type inference between forEach closure and for loop in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

Let's say you have a generic type signature for a simple map operation:

```
type Mapper = <T>(array: T[], f: (item: T) => T) => T[];
```

(maps to the same type for brevity)

When I implement it like this, compiler does not complain:

```
let map: Mapper = function (array, f) {
  let result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let item = array[i];
    result.push(f(item));
  }

  return result;
}
```

I'm using a for loop here, getting the item from array and pushing the resulting value after function application to the result, then return it. All works fine. If I replace the for loop with forEach however:

```
let map: Mapper = function (array, f) {
  let result = [];
  
  array.forEach(item => {
    result.push(f(item));
  });

  return result;
}
```

...for the result variable in the function body, typescript complains:

> Variable 'result' implicitly has type 'any[]' in some locations where
> its type cannot be determined

Typescript language server seems to resolve "item" in the loop to T in both scenarios so I'm curious why this gets the system confused (or if I'm missing something else).

And if I'm using forEach, what can I do to "result" to appease Typescript? I can set the type of result to any[] explicitly, it works (and even the returned value is correctly typed) but I suspect that is not what I'm supposed to use. From my understanding, I shouldn't have to resort to "any" here. Do you have any pointers?

Comment: Why use `forEach` for a mapping operation, rather than `map`? TypeScript understands it with `map` ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmSAnKBeKAeAKgPgBRxJJwgBcUWA2gLoA0UAZuXgJbAQC25WAlGjhT6oBVagG4AsAChpAGwjAoHBOXiIIKdAwCuAOwDGwFgHtdUAkRL0GfAN7SoUeYqQQAzttmL0hYiAB0ymCs7Bz8UGycPJJSjq7A2khmrh5eMQC+0kA)). Using `forEach` with a side effect complicates things, apparently to the point it's not worth TS figuring it out...

Comment: I'm not trying to map anything, this is a simplified example for a type system related question. It is meant as an example. Pretend it is not a map but something else with a forEach vs. for loop in between.

Comment: Well, you asked it as a mapping question, you can see why people thought mapping was part of the question. Anyway, I'm with CertainPerformance on the basic type inference issue being side-effects.

Comment: The question title refers to forEach closure vs. for loop - that was what the question about. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general problem is that, given a *callback* passed to a function, TypeScript can't infer when the callback will be called, if ever. With

```
array.forEach(item => {
    result.push(f(item));
});
```

The code that pushes to `result` is not in the `map` function proper; it's inside a *callback* inside the `map` function.

In contrast, with `for` loops (and with pretty much any code that doesn't involve a callback), when the logic involves just a *plain function body*, without callback nesting, TS can automatically understand and propagate the types as you're expecting.

I think the best approach here (not only to make TS happy, but to make your code easier to maintain in general) is to avoid callbacks with side-effects. In this case, instead of pushing to an outside array as a side-effect, use `Array.prototype.map` to create the new array all at once.

```
let map: Mapper = function (array, f) {
    return array.map(f);
}
```

TypeScript generally works best when data is transformed in a more [functional/pure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11607927/what-does-pure-mean-in-the-context-of-programming-languages-and-paradigms) manner, instead of as a result of side-effects. It's not *necessary*, but it makes automatic type inference easier and can help you avoid from having to explicitly note types.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. Map is not important here, was meant as an example - can be any function with a loop within it. If I were to use a callback / forEach in here, would I have any other recourse other than setting result to any[] here?

Comment: @RestOfTheBothWorlds If you defined the function type inline, you could do `const result: T[] = [];`. More generally, for whatever the particular situation is, *try hard* to find a more functional alternative - one usually exists, and will make things easier type-wise.

Comment: Relevant GitHub issue: [microsoft/TypeScript#9998: Trade-offs in Control Flow Analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)