# Is a prefix or postfix operator in the global scope a side effect?

Tags: javascript, definition, side-effects, postfix-operator

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29):

> In computer science, a function or expression is said to have a side effect if it modifies some state outside its scope or has an observable interaction with its calling functions or the outside world.

From [You Don't Know JS](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch5.md#expression-side-effects)

> There are other side-effecting expressions, though. For example:

```
var a = 42;
var b = a++;
```

I get that 42 is assigned to b and then a becomes 43. However, since a and b are both in the global scope why would this be considered a side effect?

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: The Wikipedia author might have a different idea of `scope` of an expression than JavaScript - as this article is language agnostic. Later in the same article, variable assignments in C++ are considered side-effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most strict definition, every assignment to a variable is a side-effect as it fits with this example given in the Wikipedia article:

> For example, a particular function might [...] modify one of its arguments

So this is also true for `a++`: it may not be a function in the JavaScript terminology, but operators are just a different syntax for what in general could be called a function.

However, in *practical* use of the term, an operation is said to have a side-effect when it is a "bad" side-effect, i.e. when that function also has another effect, one that is considered the *main* effect, given the context in which it occurs.

For instance, let's say you have a function that modifies its argument and returns a value. For example `Array.prototype.push`. If this function is called and its return value is ignored, then we would *in practice* not say there was a side effect, even though strictly speaking there is:

```
a = [];
a.push('x');
```

In the most strict sense even the assignment operator in `a = [];` would imply a side-effect (since *a* is modified), but in common speech we would not consider that a (bad) side-effect either.

However, when you use the return value of `a.push('x')`, then two effects play a role: the returned value, and the modification of *a*. In that case, the context would make that return value the *main* effect, and the mutation of *a* the side-effect:

```
a = [];
if (a.push('x') == 1) {
    console.log('you have one element in your array');
}
```

Here we certainly have a *side-effect*, both in the strict and common meaning of the term. The context now is an evaluated expression, and so the return value of `push` plays the main role here. The mutation of *a* becomes the side-effect.

The same happens in your example. If `a++;` occurs as a statement, i.e. the returned value is not used, then we would not commonly call it a (bad) side-effect:

```
a++;
```

However, when also the return value is used, we do say it has a side-effect:

```
b = a++;
```

Again, this is according to the practical use of the term in colloquial speech; in the strict sense, `a++` always represents a side effect.

Some more reading on SO:

- [What is a “side effect?”](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect)
- [Functional Programming: Side effects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5381901/functional-programming-side-effects)