# Find out if two variables inherit from the same parameterized type in Scala

Tags: scala

here is my Problem:

I try to aggregate a List of Objects:

```
val list = List(Foo(1), Foo(2), Bar(2), Bar(3), Baz(5), Baz(3))
```

After the aggregation i want to have only one object for every *aggregatable* type in this list. In this Example Foo and Bar should be aggregatable where Baz isn't, so the result should be:

```
List(Foo(3), Bar(5), Baz(5), Baz(3))
```

My Idea was to define a trait Aggregatable as follows:

```
trait Aggregatable[T] {
    def aggregate(agg: T): T
}

case class Foo(val x: Int) extends Aggregatable[Foo] {
    def aggregate(agg: Foo) = {
        val x = (0 /: List(this, agg))((old, elem) => (old + elem.x))
        new Foo(x)
    }
}

case class Bar(val x: Int) extends Aggregatable[Bar] {
    def aggregate(agg: Bar) = {
        val x = (0 /: List(this, agg))((old, elem) => (old + elem.x))
        new Bar(x)
    }   
}

case class Baz(val x: Int)
```

Well, I think this is the obvious part of the Problem...

In the next step I try to aggregate the list. First I group the list into lists of homogenious types:

```
val grouped = list.groupBy( _.getClass().toString() )

/* => grouped should be
 * Map(
 *     class Foo -> 
 *         List(Foo(1), Foo(2)),
 *     class Bar -> 
 *         List(Bar(3), Bar(4)), 
 *     class Baz -> 
 *         List(Baz(5), Baz(3))
 * )
 */
```

Now for the sake of simplicity lets now assume that we want to find out if the first two elements of the first list are aggregatable:

```
val firstList = grouped.toList.apply(0)._2 // List(Foo(1), Foo(2))
val a = firstList (0) // Foo(1)
val b = firstList (1) // Foo(2)
```

This is where my actual problem begins. To determine if a and b can be aggregated, there must be a way to ask if a and b inherit from the same type Aggregatable[T] for some fixed T.

My way to ask this was to define a type aggregatablePair:

```
type aggregatablePair = Pair[T, T] forSome { type T <: Aggregatable[T] }
```

Build a pair out of a and b:

```
val pair = (a, b)
```

and aggregate them if they are an aggregatablePair:

```
pair match {
    case aggPair: aggregatablePair => aggPair._1.aggregate(aggPair._2)
    case _ => println("pair is not aggregatable")
}
```

but this doesn't work... the error is:

```
type mismatch; 
found: aggPair._2.type (with underlying type T forSome { type T <: Aggregatable[T] })
required: T where type T <: Aggregatable[T]
```

In my opinion it sounds like the found type matches the required type... can anyone tell me why it dosn't?
And what would be the right way to express what I want?

thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a quite "satisfying" solution to my problem. The general Idea is to add a method aggregateOrCons with result type List[Any] to the Aggregatable trait, which either aggregates two Objects if they are from the same type or returns a list containing the input arguments.

```
trait Aggregatable[T] {
    def aggregate(agg: T): T

    def aggregateOrCons(agg: Any): List[Any] = {
        agg match {
            case t: T => List(this.aggregate(t))
            case a => List(a, this)
        }
    }
}
```

My input parameters are now being sorted instead of grouped by their class, because I only need to ensure that objects of the same type appear in a row.

```
val list = List(new Foo(1), new Baz(1), new Baz(2), new Bar(3), new Foo(2), new Bar(4))
val sorted = list.sortWith(
    (a1, a2) => (a1.getClass().toString() compareTo a2.getClass().toString()) < 0
)
```

In the next step I define a method to aggregate two objects of type Any. If both input arguments are of type Aggregatable, I apply the aggregatableOrCons method on them (which will result either the aggregation of the two arguments, if they are equal, or a list containing the arguments if they are not). If one of them is no Aggregatable a list containing the input arguments will be returned.

```
def aggregate(a: Any, b: Any): List[Any] = a match {
    case agg1: Aggregatable[_] => b match {
        case agg2: Aggregatable[_] => agg1.aggregateOrCons(agg2)
        case b => List(b, agg1)
    }
    case a => List(b, a)
}
```

Now the only requirement left to be able to fold the list of sorted input artuments is a neutral element. It should aggregate with anything and should just return the input argument.

```
object NeutralAggregatable extends Aggregatable[Any] {
    def aggregate(agg: Any) = agg
}
```

Now I can fold the sorted list

```
val neutral: Any = NeutralAggregatable
val aggregated = (List(neutral) /: sorted)((old, elem) => 
    (aggregate(old.head, elem) ::: old.tail)
)

println(aggregated) // List(Foo(3), Baz(2), Baz(1), Bar(7))
```

Comment: Afaics, your solution subsumes to `List[Any]` and loses the typing. You might as well be programming in a unityped (dynamic) language. That is why I suggested you do it with Monoid.

Comment: It is true, that my solution results to a List[Any] but this does not mean that I loose the typing (the type of my input list is List[Any] too). The solution I posted here is of course a simple example of my actual problem where I start and end with a List of a more special type. In my programm I use this list so gather "instructions" but since some of these instructions need user input I want to aggregate them before working them of, to minimize user input. While working these instructions off I use pattern matching since there is only a finite number of instructions.

Comment: But if there is another simpler solution (e.g. with Monoids) I'd be glad to see it.

Comment: Okay I am bit burned out right now on SO. I will try to come back to this. Perhaps try asking at [Tony Morris's blog](http://blog.tmorris.net/) or [Apocalisp's](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com). They are both on SO too. You probably must explicitly ask them not to give you a typeclass (Haskell-like) solution, unless you want that. Since Tony prefers typeclass approach. I prefer subtyping.

Answer (score 0):

A type parameter `T` can't be determined at runtime, due to the type erasure of the JVM. But you don't need to (and you know what `T` is because it is also the class from `getClass` keys in the map, but you don't need to know).

Since you know that `a` and `b` are the same type (e.g. `Foo`), then if `a.instanceOf[Aggregatable]` (or `a.instanceOf[Aggregatable[_]]`), then `b.instanceOf[Aggregatable]` is too. So just test the first item of the list and if true, accumulate all elements.

---

P.S. I would have used a [category theory collection library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722726/is-the-scala-2-8-collections-library-a-case-of-the-longest-suicide-note-in-hist/7397388#7397388), that has a `Monoid` type, rather than reinventing it as `Aggregatable`. `Monoid` knows how to accumulate itself. See page 7 of [Applicative programming with effects](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.pdf#page=7).

Conceptually you are doing the following [functional programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602444/what-is-functional-declarative-and-imperative-programming) steps.

1. Fold over the list creating a collection (e.g. list or map) of lists, collating items of the same type in distinct lists. Use `elem.getClass` to test for distinctness.
2. Map the collection of lists, folding each sub-list to accumulate.

I see you accomplished #1 with `groupBy`.

Comment: I think this does not work. The Problem is, that I need the type T - not the Aggregatable[_], because the type T has implemented aggregate(t: T): T for some known T while I don't know the type T, when I cast to Aggregatable[_].

Comment: Another problem is, that (as far as I know) I cannot cast to a type if I only have its class object, as this would mean that the actual type is not known until runtime which would contradict to the strongly typed concept of scala.

Comment: This also means that defining Monoids wont help me either. I can indeed define a monoid for Foo and Bar but since the compiler cannot know at compile time which monoid to apply this approach wont work either.

Comment: I hope you will understand if I don't have the time to explain further beyond what I already wrote in my answer. I still think the answer I gave was correct. Perhaps I will endeavor to write the complete code for this in my new language at some point, to show how it is done with Monoid. Thanks for the feedback. Glad to see you found what you believe to be an adequate solution.

Comment: do you mean the language described at http://copute.com which used to be linked on your profile?