# Is functional programming a type of declarative programming?

Tags: functional-programming, declarative-programming

I am aware that declarative programming just passes the input and expects the output without stating the procedure how it is done. In functional programming, is a programming paradigm, which takes an input and returns an output. When I checked the Higher order functional programming, we pass a function to map/reduce, which does not reveal the procedure how it is done. So is higher order functional programming and declarative programming the same thing??

Comment: No. Functional programming is not per se the same as declarative programming and vice versa. Prolog - which is logical programming - is by many considered to be a declarative programming language as well. But the terms are in my opinion a bit "fuzzy".

Comment: See this previous SO question for related answers: [Functional, Declarative, and Imperative Programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602444/functional-declarative-and-imperative-programming).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Short answer**: **No**.

*Wikipedia* defines [*declarative programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming*) as:

> In computer science, declarative programming is a programming
>   paradigm - a style of building the structure and elements of computer
>   programs - that **expresses the logic of a computation without describing
>   its control flow**.

Or to state it a bit boldly: "Say *what* you want, not *how* you want it.".

This is thus in contrast with *imperative* programming languages where a program is seen as a *set of instructions* that are done one after another. The fact that `map`, etc. *do not reveal the procedure* does not make it declarative: one can use a lot of C libraries that are proprietary and do not allow you to inspect the source code. That however, does not mean that these are declarative.

The definition of [*functional programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) on the other hand is:

> In computer science, functional programming is a programming paradigm
>   - a style of building the structure and elements of computer programs - that treats computation as the evaluation of mathematical functions and avoids changing-state and mutable data. It **is a declarative
>   programming paradigm**, which means programming is done with expressions
>   or declarations instead of statements.

Based on these definitions one could say that *functional programming is a subset of declarative programming*. In a practical sense however if we follow the *strict* definitions, no programming language nowadays is purely, and un-ambigously *declarative* or *functional*. One can however say that *Haskell is* more *declarative than Java*.

Declarative programming is usually considered to be "safer" since people tend to have trouble managing side-effects. A lot of programming errors are the result of not taking all side effects into account. On the other hand it is hard to

1. *design* a language that allows a programmer to describe what he wants without going into details on *how* to do it;
2. implement a *compiler* that will generate - based on such programs - an *efficient* implementation; and
3. some problems have *inherent* side effects. For instance if you work with a database, a network connection or a file system, then reading/writing to a file for instance is supposed to have side effects. One can of course decide not to make this part of the programming language (for instance many constraint programming languages do not allow these type of actions, and are a "sub language" in a larger system).

There have been several attempts to design such language. The most popular are - in my opinion - *logic programming*, *functional programming*, and *constraint programming*. Each has its merits and problems. We can also observe this declarative approach in for instance *databases* (like SQL) and text/XML processing (with *XSLT*, *XPath*, *regular expressions*,...) where one does *not* specify how a query is resolved, but simply specifies through for instance the regular expression what one is looking for.

Whether a programming language is however declarative, is a bit of a fuzzy discussion. Although programming languages, modeling languages and libraries like Haskell, Prolog, Gecode,... have definitely made programming more declarative, these are probably not declarative in the most strict sense. In the most *strict* sense, one should think that regardless *how* you write the logic, the compiler will always come up with the same result (although it might take a bit longer).

Say for instance we want to check whether a list is empty in Haskell. We can write this like:

```
is_empty1 :: [a] -> Bool
is_empty1 [] = True
is_empty1 (_:_) = False
```

We can however write it like this as well:

```
is_empty2 :: [a] -> Bool
is_empty2 l = length l == 0
```

Both should give the same result for the same queries. If we however give it an infinite list, `is_empty1 (repeat 0)` will return `False` whereas `is_empty2 (repeat 0)` will loop forever. So that means that we somehow still wrote some "control flow" into the program: we have defined - to some extent - *how* Haskell should evaluate this. Although lazy programming will result in the fact that a programmer does not really specify what should be evaluated first, there are still specifications how Haskell will evaluate this.

According to some people, this is the difference between *programming* and *specifying*. One of my professors once stated that according to him, the difference is that when you program something, you have somehow control about *how* something is evaluated, whereas when you *specify* something, you have no control. But again, this is only *one* of the many definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely, functional programming emphasises more on what to compute rather than how to compute. However, there are patterns available in functional programming that are pretty much control flow patterns you would commonly associate with declarative programming, take for example the following control flow:

```ml
let continue = ref true in
while !continue do
  ...
  if cond then continue := false
  else
     ...
done
```

Looks familiar huh? Here you can see some declarative constructs but this time round we are in more control.